# how to split the array objects into same array based on reapeted object elements

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

Say i have an array like this :

```
 var arr=[
 
 {
  "favnumber": 20,
  "studentname": "mohan",
  "Studentage": 18
  },
 {
   "favnumber": 22,
   "studentname": "mahesh",
  "Studentage": 19
 },
 {
  "favnumber": 22,
  "studentname": "emam",
  "Studentage": 19
  },
 {
  "favnumber": 20,
  "studentname": "mamtha",
  "Studentage": 18
 }

];
```

now i have to split the objects based on the repeated object keys :
i have tried many methods could not resolve .
expected output:

```
  [
  {
   "favnumber": 20,
  "studentname": "mohan",
  "Studentage": 18
  },
  {
  "favnumber": 22,
  "studentname": "mahesh",
  "Studentage": 19
  }
  ],
  [
  {
  "favnumber": 22,
  "studentname": "emam",
  "Studentage": 19
   }
   ],
   [
   {
  "favnumber": 20,
  "studentname": "mamtha",
  "Studentage": 18
    }
    ]
```

now i have to split the objects based on the repeated object keys :
now i have to split the objects based on the repeated object keys :

thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask]. Try to show some effort in resolving your own issue. You asked already too many questions without any sight of code with a specific issue. [edit] and provide a [mcve] of a **specific problem**.

Comment: Also... `[[` makes no sense. Why would you want a 2D array?

Comment: i have changed expected output

Comment: Changing your output array didn't made your question any more valuable in terms of what you have tried so far. PS: Your input array is still troublesome I think. No?!

Comment: Do you intend to group objects from the array together based on a certain value they have in common? (for example having the same value for the key `favnumber`). Your description is not very clear, you wrote "split objects" but it seems that you intend the opposite (group some of them together).

Comment: exactly same i am looking for